# Is there an idiom or proverb about being unfair about dividing things, property, money, etc?

Tags: adverbs, idiom-requests

I`m looking for an idiom, proverb or just expression in English, which would describe a person who becomes unfair and unjust when it comes to dividing money, or property with others,thus trying to grab more for himself/herself ?

Comment: What research would you like to post?

Most obviously, your person would be "greedy" but did you mean anything so simple, or not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin the request was for an idiom - which might be a little broad for a question but not quite as easily searchable as  words like greedy (and greedy is not necessarily unfair : )  - it's about desire for more which often provokes one to be unfair ... but many proverbs about greed would probably work

Comment: The question could be more clear if you were more interested in the unjust part or the greed part.  "Self-dealing" is a term (not an idiom) frequently used for doling out things in an advantageous way for oneself.  It would be less applicable to taking more than ones share of the money but more applicable of choosing the best two items out of 4 and leaving you with the lesser 'half'.   I'd make it an answer if you clarified your purpose and it fit your purpose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-dealing

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin it's more a matter of the request for an idiom or not.  My thoughts on the word greed are more splitting hairs and a comment on the word, not a disqualification of the word outright.  ( which I could elaborate on but that could be mind reading of intent - with some intent of the OP greedy would be a word that could work)

Comment: @Tom22 Yes, you`re right. it`s not solely about greediness. It`s more about becoming unfair when it comes to dividing something. Of course, partly it implies being greedy but the emphasis is on not being honest. For example - we`ve bought a pizza and cut it into 6 equal parts. You took 4 of them, leaving only 2 for me. You`re greedy but at the same time, you decision was unfair so you`re also dishonest.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Bosses nearly always decide to pay themselves more than they pay the actual *workers*. Is that because they's *greedy*, or because (they, at least, think) they *deserve* more?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Could you please tell me, what part of my comment seems " bad " to you,  in terms of linguistics ? Thanks.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In linguistic terms, you comments leave much to be desired, so, instead of coming with irrelevant replies, please, be more productive. Either stop commenting or express your point of view backed with evidence, in a respectful manner, pertinent to my original question.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin You know, in my native language we have this saying - " if sorry was a drug, it would be sold in pharmacies ". Be respectful to others and always express your opinion in a polite manner. Words are like arrows, once loosed, you cannot call them back. I can take constructive criticism well, but not rudeness and impoliteness. That is all I can say. Let us call it quits. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible idiom asserting that someone is taking advantage by cheating in measurement - it is a bit dated and not exactly about a division of items but it might get people started.

> [**thumb on the scale** from the free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thumb+on+the+scale)
>
> A method of deception or manipulation that creates an unfair advantage for the swindler, likened to a merchant holding a thumb on the scale when weighing goods for sale, therefore increasing the weight and price.
>
> *You have to suspect that the casinos have their thumb on the scale when it comes to the slot machines. There's no way you're getting fair odds.*

The expression is used with justice more specifically too.

You can find many many google hits for "**thumb on the scale of justice**"  many from reputable publications.

In regards to justice it implies that a party is deliberately weighing factors with bad faith to reach a conclusion they find more valuable.

Whether or not the idiom is exactly what the OP is looking for is another thing.

It also has a risk of being cliche - like many expressions and idioms.

Answer (score 3):

> Professor Neurus is also memorable for his way of distributing the
>   spoils after a criminal act: "**One for you, two for me**."

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Hijitus)  'The Adventures of Hijitus'

Comment: I think this could be a useful idiom.  It can be used loosely too  -  "It's always two for him" almost stands on it's own "It's always two for him and one for me" (flipping it) certainly works.  'always' helps emphasis it's about their nature.  "Two for him and one for the next guy"  would also be understood idiomatically imo

Answer (score 1):

'Take the lion's share' is often used in a non-pejorative way (Food takes the lion's share of what's left after taxes).

However, [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lion-s-share) licenses the pejorative usage:

> **lion's share** [noun]
>
> 1.the largest part or share, especially a disproportionate portion:
>
> *The eldest son received the lion's share of the estate.*

'Disproportionate' must reference [un]fairness / [in]appropriateness here, as obviously the largest share constitutes the largest proportion.